# Facebook Connect cancel button not working

Tags: api, facebook

I'm using facebook connect for a little website. This is my pop-up request URL:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=".$app_id."&redirect_uri=".urlencode($redirect_url)."&scope=email,read_stream,publish_stream,publish_checkins,offline_access,friends_checkins,user_checkins&display=popup
```

The problem is, I have to buttons: Login and Cancel. When I click on cancel I go back to the login page, instead of closing the window. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a desired behavior of [OAuth Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/) no matter which button user is clicks redirection (to URL specified in `redirect_uri`) occurs.

Some of the reasons that window isn't closed by clicking on *Cancel* and additional notes:

- Closing of windows not opened by script is blocked in most browsers by default.
- Closing of window is a feature that require JavaScript solution and OAuth dialog URL provides ability not to rely on this.
- You can use JS-SDK with `FB.login` which will provide this for you and will close dialog.